# File with "|"s in Atom editor has smiley faces printed from Python; split("|") doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an input file I'm trying to process with Python, which appears to have content like the following:

```
# This works, when run at a REPL
line = 'aababasdf|75=2|asdfa|150=17|asdfasdf'
date = line.split('|75=')[1].split('|',1)[0]
```

When I run the above by hand, or copy-and-paste the file's contents from Atom, it works. However, when I have the Python open the file and read the line itself, it fails:

```
# This fails, reading from the file from which contents were copy-and-pasted
with open(filename) as curfile:
    for line in curfile:
        date = line.split('|75=')[1].split('|',1)[0]
```

This code fails with an IndexError: the `split()` creates only a single segment, so no `[1]` segment exists.

When I print the line from the file-based code, it prints smiley faces where the `|`s should be.

What could be going wrong here? How can I better debug this scenario?

Comment: Please post the code :)

Comment: Hard to tell you what's wrong with no code.

Comment: Also please format your question to make it clear to others!

Comment: Very likely there is an encoding issue with the input file.

Comment: you can use regex instead of split to extra whatever is coming after the =

Comment: @Hamoudaq given the specific nature of the actual file, I need to be able to search for the entirety of "|75=". Would regex allow me to do that where split is failing?

Comment: @AndrewKerrigan, ...it's not yet been shown that `split()` is doing anything wrong. Why don't you start by demonstrating that in a way others can reproduce, before we start getting into alternate approaches? **Ideally**, you could avoid the complexity here (of multiple split() calls), and just have a specific call, like `'foo|75=121897'.split('|75=')`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The issue is that when I copy and paste the string directly into the code it works just fine, so I wanted to show that it was an issue with the file. The file itself contains sensitive information that I can't share here, so I was unsure how else to communicate the issue.

Comment: @AndrewKerrigan, I'd suggest logging `repr(line)` for every line processed; that'll let you find the one that fails, and then sanitize it to the simplest contents it could include that still generate the bug. One way or another, you need to provide enough information for someone else to reproduce the issue before anyone can reasonably be expected to help.

Comment: @ekhumoro that was my inclination, but I have no idea how to go about resolving that issue or what additional information I would need to provide for you to be able to help

Comment: @AndrewKerrigan, ...moreover, logging the output of `repr()` will provide something that distinguishes between different characters that *look* identical when rendered, which would diagnose the issue @MarkRansom is referring to.

Comment: When I used the repr(line) that CharlesDuffy suggested, the line was printed with "\x01" in place of where all the "|" symbols should be

Comment: Well, there you are -- your file isn't actually `|`-delimited at all. Use `line.split('\x01')` and you'll be fine.

Comment: @AndrewKerrigan. Can you give some idea how these files are created and/or what **kind** of information they contain? They are obviously encoded/formated in a very specific way, and without more clues it's hard to give concrete suggestions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Awesome that appears to have worked perfectly! I tried googling what repr() does but it's a bit unclear. Do you mind clarifying what that function does differently versus when I was just printing the line directly?

Comment: (BTW, if you want to get some kind of proof/demonstration of what the actual content of the file is, open it up in a hex editor -- [Fhred](http://frhed.sourceforge.net/en/) is one option for Windows under an open-source license, suggested via [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/14465/hex-editors-for-windows)).

Comment: `repr()` prints a line in such a way that when parsed by a Python interpreter, it'll evaluate back to itself (to the extent possible; this always works for strings; not all object types have full implementations).

Comment: What editor are you viewing the file with that shows those characters as vertical bars?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Awesome thank you for the help! My apologies for the initial question being incomplete/unclear. Bad combination of being new to the site/working with sensitive information meant that I may have struggled to write the question in the most clear format.

Comment: @MarkRansom Atom. When I open the original file in atom, it shows them as vertical bars, and then when I run the script and it prints the line (prior to adding repr()), it represents it (plus one of the numbers before or after it) as a ☺

Comment: @AndrewKerrigan, ...FWIW, personally, I think Mark's answer addresses this question properly enough that there's no need for me to add a competing one. If you agree, you might accept it by clicking the checkbox next to it (which will mark the question solved); if you disagree, you might comment on that answer asking for further clarification.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the edit of the question! I'll definitely look back on your re-working when writing future questions under similar circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running this from the Windows console (code page 437) there are two vertical bar characters: `b'\x7c'` and `b'\xb3'`. The first is part of the ASCII character set, and the second is one of the line-drawing characters that were part of the original PC.

```
>>> print(b'\x7c\xb3'.decode('cp437'))
|│
```

In addition you appear to be using a text editor that shows `b'\x01'` as a vertical bar as well. That's a non-standard way of displaying that character, which is generally invisible since it's an ASCII/Unicode control character.

Once you've figured out the *actual* character in the file, you can substitute it in your `split` call.

Comment: Do you know which codepage/font/&c. could cause `\x01` to render as a pipe (as the OP appears to be reporting)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I can't figure that one out either. When I first read the question I missed the part where they said it was printing out as a smiley face, which indeed is `\x01` in cp437.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've made the necessary edits to the answer, I think it matches the question sufficiently.